# How to get result in JSONObject form from MongoDb using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch `Distinct` data from MongoDb using NodeJs.I am getting data in JSONArray form as I am not getting key from MongoDb.

Below is my code:

```
const coll = client.db("mydb").collection("ItemsAddedByAdmin");
coll.distinct("product_name",(function(err,docs){                     
   res.send({"product_name":docs});
}));
```

**Below is my OUTPUT**

```
{
"product_name": [
    "Biology",
    "Chemistry",
    "Crown",
    "Crown Junior",
    "Long Book",
    "Long Book A4",
    "Physics",
    "Sketch Book",
    "Universal"
  ]
}
```

and when I am trying below code I am getting no values.

```
const coll = client.db("mydb").collection("ItemsAddedByAdmin");
coll.distinct("product_name",(function(err,docs){
   let output = docs.map(r => ({'product_name':docs.product_name}));
   res.send(output);                        
}));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

I want values in key value pair like given below:

```
[
 {
   "product_name":Book
 },
 {
   "product_name":Pencil
 }  
]
```

Someone please let me know how can I get desired result any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small change and it should start working:

```
const coll = client.db("mydb").collection("ItemsAddedByAdmin");
coll.distinct("product_name",(function(err,docs){

      let output = docs.map(r => ({'product_name':r})); // r contains the item of array at respective index
      res.send(output);       

}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use only r in your map function

```
 let output = docs.map( r => ({'product_name': r}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('coll').find({},{product_name:1,_id:0})
```

Comment: This will return same values available in database and not distinct.